# Do not send me emails about questions written by me (even if they have a tag I am subscribed to)

Tags: feature-request, tags, email-notification, subscription

I subscribed to the tag "ecm", so I often receive such emails:

[image]

**PROBLEM:** Many of these email are about questions written by me.
*(I am quite active in that field, usually answering but also often asking)*

Would it be possible to not send me emails about questions written by me?